# jqGrid password confirmation

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to create a password confirmation input in a jqGrid form but i believe that i'm doing it the wrong way. The reason for this is that in my implementation, when you edit an already defined user both fields (password and password_confirm) contain the users password with asterisks.

There is  nothing wrong with that, but i believe that its better to have both fields empty on edit, and validate them only when they contain values. This is part of the code:

> colNames:["Name","Username","Email", "Password","Confirm Password"],
>
> colModel:[{name:"name",index:"name",editable:true,editrules:{required:true}},
>
> *other fields* ....
>
> {name:"password",index:"password",editable:true,edittype:"password",hidden:true,editrules:{edithidden:true,required:true} },
>   {name:"confirm_password",index:"confirm_password",editable:true,edittype:"password",hidden:true,editrules:{edithidden:true,required:true}},

As you can see i've defined 2 objects, one for the actual password and another one for the confirmation and when i populate the grid, i return for both fields the same value.

Any thoughts for better implementation?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

have been searching for an answer to this for a while, the I came up with my own solution. I didn't want to add a field in the DB - Redis in my case - so I needed to create a field for password check on the fly, and verify that it matched the first password field. The password check field is going to be submitted to the backend, this is not a bug, but a feature.

On with the code.

The first function we define is the one that will create the password check field and append it to the original password field:

```
    function createPassCheck(el) {
            // Create the containing table row
            var passCheck = $("<tr></tr>").addClass("FormData")
                    .attr({
                            id: "tr_passwordCheck",
                            rowpos: 20
                    });
            // Create a cell for the label and add it to the row
            var passCheckLabelTd = $("<td></td>")
                    .addClass("CaptionTD").text("Password Check");
            passCheck.append(passCheckLabelTd);
            // Prepare the cell for the input box. All
            // the cells have a non breaking space, we add
            // one as well to keep aligned. We then add it to the row.
            var passCheckTd = $("<td>&nbsp;</td>")
                    .addClass("DataTD");
            passCheck.append(passCheckTd);
            // Create an input box, and add it to the input cell 
            var passCheckInput = $("<input></input>")
                    .addClass("FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all")
                    .attr({
                            id: "passwordCheck",
                            name: "passwordCheck",
                            role: "textbox",
                            type: "password"
                    });
            passCheckTd.append(passCheckInput);
            // Finally append the row to the table, we have been called after
            // the creation of the password row, it will be appended after it.
            var tbodyEl = el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
            tbodyEl.appendChild(passCheck[0]);
    }
```

Before we can move on we need to add one other function, a key one: it's the one that will check if the two passwords match.

```
    function customPassCheck(cellvalue, cellname) {
            // Get a reference to the password check input box. You see
            // the 'tr_passwordCheck' id we are using? We set that id in
            // the function "createPassCheck".
            var passCheckVal = $("#tr_passwordCheck input").val()

            // If both fields are empty or the passwords match
            // we can submit this form.
            if (
                    (cellvalue == "" && passCheckVal == "")
                    ||
                    cellvalue == passCheckVal      
               ) {
                    return [true, ""];
            }

            // Can you guess why we are here?
            return [false, "Password and password check don't match."];
    }
```

Finally a function we will use to make the password blank on edit, we will do this by registering as a custom formatter.

```
    function customPassFormat(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            // When asked to format a password for display, simply
            // show a blank. It will make it a bit easier when
            // we editing an object without changing the password.
            return "";
    }
```

We can now define out password field in in jqGrid and make it special:

```
jQuery("#crud").jqGrid({
....
....
colModel:[
  ....
  {
     name:'password',
     index:'password', 
     width:80,
     align:"right",
     editable:true,
     // It is hidden from the table view... 
     hidden: true,
     editrules:{
       // ...but we can edit it from the panel
       edithidden: true, 
       // We are using a custom verification
       custom:true, 
       // This is the function we have created
       // to verify the passwords
       custom_func: customPassCheck
     },
     edittype: 'password',
     // Our custom formatter that will blank the 
     // password when editing it
     formatter: customPassFormat,
     editoptions: {
       // This is where the magic happens: it will add
       // the password check input on the fly when editing
       // from the editing panel.
       dataInit: createPassCheck  
     }
   },
....
....
```

That's all folks!

Fabio